# Subtrair elementos de um array bidimensional

Tags: ruby

Tenho um array

```
x = [[2,5,16,26],[5,28,35,46],[1,9,28,54,60,102],[...]...]
```

Os arrays dentro do array não tem tamanhos fixos, podem conter de 1 a N elementos. Como faço para ter um novo array `y` com a subtração de cada elemento pelo seu antecessor, se houver. Ex:

```
[[3,11,10],[23,7,11],[8,19,26,6,42]
```

O 3 é a subtração de 5-2, o 11, 16-5 etc. E nesse array `y` o índice começando por 1.

Comment: essa pergunta é um dever de casa ou se aplica a algum problema específico? Seria interessante contextualizar. Além disso, você poderia dizer qual solução você está pensando e quais as suas dificuldades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode utilizar o método [**`each_cons`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons). Observe:

```
a = [1, 8, 17, 20]
a.each_cons(2) {|pair| p pair }

#=> [1, 8]
#=> [8, 17]
#=> [17, 20]
```

Com base nisso pode fazer o seguinte:

```
x = [[2, 5, 16, 26], [5, 28, 35, 46], [1, 9, 28, 54, 60, 102]]
r = x.map{|e| e.each_cons(2).map{|pair| pair[1] - pair[0] } }

#=> [[3, 11, 10], [23, 7, 11], [8, 19, 26, 6, 42]]
```

Comment: Preciso ler mais sobre os métodos de array.